# is there a method to display fields in the same div in django forms?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

in my forms.py

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    check = forms.BooleanField(
        label='Actif',
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
            attrs={'class': 'styled'}
        ),
        initial=True
    )

    check_2 = forms.BooleanField(
        label='Actif_2',
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
            attrs={'class': 'styled'}
        ),
        initial=True
    )
```

in models.py

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    check = models.BooleanField(default='True')
    check_2 = models.BooleanField(default='True')
```

in html :

```
    <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="." method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% crispy form %}
            </form>
    </div>
```

like this i have in output form :

```
# check 

# check_2
```

i wanto to display "check" and "check_2" in the same div : check in the left and check_2 in the right :

```
  # check                                                                                           # check_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could render the fields manually with pure HTML or, what I mostly use, is something like [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/) to render each element individually.